# How to pass a value bool? in a switch in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

I am making a form with switches in Flutter and I would like to save the value of it, but Flutter doesn't want a value bool? so I don't know how to get my value.

Here is my code :

```
Switch(
   value: _editedProduct.myswitchvalue, //line that causes problem
   onChanged: (bool val) =>
      setState(() {
         _editedProduct = _editedProduct.copyWith(myswitchvalue: val);
     },
   ),
),
```

And here's the message of my error

```
The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)
FormProductModel _editedProduct
```

Thank you for reading me

Comment: You should post the code where you've set your `_editedProduct` and the `myswitchvalue` variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myswitchvalue is of type bool? which means it can either be null or boolean. If you are sure it is not null you can add ! like that:

```
Switch(
   value: _editedProduct.myswitchvalue!, // watch the !
   onChanged: (bool val) =>
      setState(() {
         _editedProduct = _editedProduct.copyWith(myswitchvalue: val);
     },
   ),
),
```

read more about null safety in dart here: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now !
Since I'm a beginner I am having a hard time with "?" and "!", I never think about "!" so thank you for helping me on that !

Comment: definitely this is not the best answer, it's just remove the symptom but not remove root of issue

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code hope it helps You.

Declare Bool Variable

```
bool isSwitched = false;
```

Declare your Switch Widget:

```
Switch(
      value: isSwitched,
      onChanged: (value){
        setState(() {
          isSwitched=value;
          print(isSwitched);
        });
      },
      activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
      activeColor: Colors.green,
    ),
```

Your Output -> `true`

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Actually I wanted to store the value in my class so but I resolved the problem thanks to Yair Chen, but thank you very much for answering me !